# How to use a file-resource instead of a classpath-resource in ibatis sqlMap config?

Tags: java, ibatis

I'd like to use the same ibatis sqlMapConfig on many modules.

Unfortunatly only classpath-resources seems to be allowed in the resource-attribute of my sqlMap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">
<sqlMapConfig>
    <sqlMap resource="myresource.xml" />
</sqlMapConfig>
```

This does not work:

```
    <sqlMap resource="file:/myresource.xml" />
```

Is there any way to avoid duplicity (using one ibatis-config on many classpathes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `url` attribute :

```
<sqlMap url="file:///myresource.xml" />
```

Comment: @user470370 oops, bad copy/paste, it's "url" not "resource".

Comment: ah okay. i would vote up your answer as well but i am not allowed to yet.

Comment: @user470370, I'll take care of that for you :)